# Kerr metric geodesics using EL equations

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, geodesics, kerr-metric

Let there exist a Kerr metric $ds^2$ in Boyer–Lindquist coordinates such that $$ds^2=-\left(1-\frac{r_sr}{\Sigma}\right)dt^2+\left(\frac{\Sigma}{\Delta}\right)dr^2+\Sigma d \theta^2+\left(r^2+a^2+\frac{r_sra^2}{\Sigma}\sin^2(\theta)\right)\sin^2(\theta)d \phi^2-\left(\frac{2r_sra\sin^2(\theta)}{\Sigma}\right)dt d \phi,$$
such that $$a=\frac{J}{Mc}$$ $$\Sigma=r^2+a^2\cos^2(\theta)$$ $$\Delta=r^2-r_sr+a^2$$ $$r_s=2M$$ $$L=\frac{1}{2}\left[-\left(1-\frac{r_sr}{\Sigma}\right)t'^2+\left(\frac{\Sigma}{\Delta}\right)r'^2+\Sigma  \theta'^2+\left(r^2+a^2+\frac{r_sra^2}{\Sigma}\sin^2(\theta)\right)\sin^2(\theta)\phi'^2-\left(\frac{2r_sra\sin^2(\theta)}{\Sigma}\right)t'  \phi'\right]$$ where we are letting $$c=G=1$$hence the equation of $ds^2$. To find the geodesics of the Kerr metric $ds^2$ we need to apply the Euler-Lagrange equations $$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x^\mu}-\frac{d}{d \tau}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x'^\mu}\right)=0$$ where $$x^\mu=(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)=(t,r,\theta,\phi)$$ and $$\forall x'^\mu=\frac{d x^\mu}{d \tau}.$$ In order to obtain the system of ODE geodesic equations for the Kerr metric will I just solve $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial t},\frac{\partial L}{\partial t'},\frac{\partial L}{\partial r},\frac{\partial L}{\partial r'},\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta},\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta'},\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}, \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi'}$$ then just plug them into the equations $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}-\frac{d}{d \tau}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial t'}\right)=0$$ $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial r}-\frac{d}{d \tau}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial r'}\right)=0$$ $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}-\frac{d}{d \tau}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta'}\right)=0$$ $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}-\frac{d}{d \tau}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi'}\right)=0$$ and numerically solve or is there something I am missing?

Comment: This might not directly address your question but these sources may help you: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1987SvAL...13...99S https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric#Trajectory_equations

Comment: You _can_ do it without using symmetries of the spacetime, but unless you take steps to avoid it, in practice you will suffer what is known as "energy drift"; _typically_ an orbiting solution will tend to spiral inwards over time.  A symplectic integrator will not suffer this, but is extremely non-trivial to write in this case as the equations are not "separable".  If you use the trajectory equations that @Alwin mentioned, it is possible to generate a "fake" hamiltonian to solve using a more basic symplectic integrator.  I have used this technique very successfully in my personal projects.

Comment: Incidentally, if you try to use the trajectory equations "as-is" you will get stuck dealing with the square roots!

Comment: @m4r35n357 Wouldnt we arive at the trajectory equations by just applying the Euler-Lagrange equations on the Lagrangian $L$ and then using constants to manipulate the results?

Comment: If I understand you, then yes.  But those constants need to be derived somehow!  This is done using Hamilton-Jacobi analysis, which is beyond my skills, so I only speak here of _using_ the equations.

Comment: @m4r35n357 ok thanks for the clarification. So basically its just a matter of solving the parital derivatives then plugging them back into the EL equations and then manipulating those with Hamilton-Jacobi analysi?

Comment: No, I think we have come full circle.  Just use the trajectory equations that @Alwin posted; the H-J analysis has already been one (by Brandon Carter if I remember correctly)!

Comment: Ok. So upon applying the EL equations for the $t$ component of the Lagrangian we obtain $$\frac{d}{d \tau}\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(-2\left(1-\frac{2mr}{\Sigma}\right)t'+\frac{4mr}{\Sigma}a\sin^2(\theta)\phi'^2\right)\right]=0$$ where this equation is the non simplified version, not incorporating any constants or symmetries in;however, this would be wrong correct? Or can it be done like this, and I simplify it in its current form? Just am trying to understand the process at arriving at the geodesic equations themselves without incorporating in any constants.

Comment: Ah OK, in that case you can either crank the handle yourself, as you seem able to do, or seek out Carter's paper; I think the details are also in MTW and other places.

Comment: So is my method correct and will it yield the same results as if I used symmetries to simplify?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes, but it is far too messy for me to actually attempt.  I only _really_ know about the numerical analysis part, and I chose to use Carter's equations for good reason!

Comment: Alright cool. Thanks for the information!

Comment: I also assume that this notion extends to all metrics aswell?